# I can't play video or take photo on Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens

I am doing 3 things,video record,take photo, play the video.

However, 3 option works on unity but when I build the app for hololens and test it, just video recording is working. I can't take photos and play the video. Basically, I am using these scripts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/locatable-camera-in-unity . The crazy part is Hololens uses flash while taking photos but I can't see my photos in the folder. Also, I can't see the holograms in recorded video.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was Unity Version I was using 2020.3.12f1. I updated to 2020.3.33f1 now video playing is working.